# What happens if I use Reno on a Ragnaros hero affected by Alexstrasza?

Tags: hearthstone

If a player becomes Ragnaros (that has a 8HP limit) by using [Majordomo Executus](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Majordomo_Executus)' deathrattle, he can subsequently play [Alexstrasza](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Alexstrasza) to increase his HP to 15.

What happens if, after suffering damage, the player summons [Reno Jackson](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Reno_Jackson), triggering his battlecry? Is 15 the new permanent maximum, or is 8 still considered "full health" for Ragnaros?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the wiki you linked:

> > Alexstrasza can be used upon the Ragnaros hero to alter its current **and maximum** Health to 15. Following this, if the Ragnaros hero takes damage **it will be possible to heal it back up to 15**

This was apparently confirmed by Blizzard employee *Zeriyah* on her now empty Twitter.

Ben Brode has also confirmed **[via twitter](https://twitter.com/bdbrode/status/582618943333920768)** that the new maximum HP is 15.

Comment: The question isn't if it's possible to heal Ragnaros back to 15 HP but what value **Reno** uses to heal. Is it 8 (baseline) or 15 (newly added bonus HP)

Comment: @Jutschge Reno heals to maximum health and this snippet says that after applying Alexstrasza the max health is 15.

Comment: I couldn't really find a video to this but I found **[this](https://www.reddit.com/r/hearthstone/comments/3sxrak/reno_jackson_fail/cx1dlo6/)** discussion in a reddit comment section. There isn't really proof for any side of the argument.

Comment: Should be easy enough to test within a few friendly staged battles.

Comment: I've independently validated this and you are correct. Incidentally the same is true for the Lord Jaraxxus hero. If Reno is used, it will be restored to 15HP.